# Keep IP and MAC address when cable is unpluged

Tags: ip, ethernet

I have an application that look for ethernet interface and only works when at least one ethernet interface with an static IP and MAC address exists. this should show in ipconfig.

I have an on-board LAN card and configured it for a static IP (192.168.137.1), but it only works when I plug it to a network or to my laptop, for example.

if I unplug cable I get "Media disconnected":

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

it only works when cable is pluged:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5183:8021:648a:e4cf%37
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

I could not do this always (connecting to my laptop). I need a way that windows assign an static IP to my LAN card when cable is unpluged.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a Loopback adapter?

Run `hdwwiz.exe` (probably as Administrator), when asked, choose "Install the hardware that I manually select from a list (Advanced)", and then choose "Network Adapters" from list. You will be provided with some virtual devices. On the left column choose "Microsoft" and on the right column choose "Microsoft Loopback Adapter".

Add this adapter and I think you will be able to assign it a static IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Install the ["Microsoft Loopback Adapter"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708322(v=ws.10).aspx) (which is meant for use with virtual machines and isn't tied to any real hardware), and assign it a dummy IP address.

1. Run "Command Prompt" in administrator mode
2. Run `hdwwiz.exe`
3. Choose "Install … manually select from a list (Advanced)"
4. Choose "Network Adapters"
5. Under "Microsoft", choose "Microsoft Loopback Adapter"

Comment: it does not work with loopback adapter, just "Ethernet adapter"

Comment: @exim: Are you talking about the _same_ adapter? In Windows there are two things that are called "loopback"; a) the special built-in 127.0.0.1 adapter, which won't work, and b) the installable Microsoft Loopback Adapter that emulates an Ethernet card, and *should* work.